# Python Arcsin Arccos radian and degree

Tags: python, degrees, radians

I am working on wind power and speed

`u` and `v`are zonal and meridional wind. (I have the values of these 2 vectors)

The wind speed is calculated by `V = np.sqrt(u2*v2)`

Wind direction is given by `α` between `0` and `360 degree`

I know this relation holds `- u / V = sin( abs(α))` and `- v / V = cos( abs(α))`

In python I am using `np.arccos` and `np.arcsin` to try to find `α` between `0` and `360` with the 2 equation above. For the first one, it returns the radian so I convert with `np.rad2deg(...)` but it gives me a value between `0` and `180 degree` for the second one, I also try to convert but it returns me a valus between `0` and `90`.

Anyone knows how to code it? I am lost :(

Answer (score 1):

The underlying problem is mathematics: cos(-x) == cos(x), so the function `acos` has only values in the [0,pi] interval. And for equivalent reasons `asin` has values in [-pi/2,pi/2] one.

But trigonometric library designers know about that, and provide a special function (`atan2`) which uses both coordinates (and not a ratio) to give a value in the [-pi, pi] interval.

That being said, be careful when processing wind values. A 360 wind is a wind coming from the North, and 90 is a wind coming from the East. Which is not the way mathematicians count angles...

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, can you explain me what do you mean by => That being said, be careful when processing wind values. A 360 wind is a wind coming from the North, and 90 is a wind coming from the East. Which is not the way mathematicians count angles...

Comment: @chantaldem: the 0 angle (in math) is x=1, y=0. This is an horizontal vector going to the right. On a standard map, the North is the up of the map. So a 360 (or 0) wind will be a vertical vector going downside. I still remember my first dynamic meteorology courses...